# Unity環境でのLive2Dキャラクターの背景描画について

Tags: unity3d

Unity上でLive2Dのキャラクターを描画させ、背景画像を表示させたいのですが、
真っ青背景が表示され、うまいこと表示されません。

Image等で背景画像を配置してみるも、どうしてもキャラクターの前面に表示されてしまいます。

レイヤー情報を持たせようと、
live2DModel.setRenderMode(Live2D.L2D_RENDER_DRAW_MESH);
を実行してみるも推奨されていないらしく、十分に調査できておりませんでしたがキャラクタの描画ができませんでした。

やりたいこととしてはPNGやJPGの背景画像をLive2Dで描画されたキャラクターの背景に表示させたいです。
どのような方法で実現できるか、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

環境：Unity4.6.1
ビルドプラットフォーム：WebPlayer、PC(Windows)Standalone

参考にしたサンプル：
http://sites.cybernoids.jp/cubism/sdk_tutorial/platform-setting/unity/csharp/sampleapp1

Answer (score 1):

背景画像はどのような方法で追加していますか？私の知る方法だと以下2つあります。

（１）背景画像は、Texture Type=TextureでPlaneの3Dオブジェクトにアタッチしてる
（２）背景画像は、Texture Type=Spriteで追加している

真っ青背景となると（１）の方法でPlaneが裏面表示されていて、Planeを回転させてあげると解決する気がします。
ちなみに２）の方法だとSpriteをSceneにドラッグ＆ドロップするだけで表示されます。

Comment: ご解答頂きありがとうございます。
またお礼が遅れてしまい申し訳ございません。

私の言っていた真っ青背景の色についてですが、
Main CameraのCameraオブジェクトのBackgroundにデフォルトで指定されていた色のことでした。（勉強不足で申し訳ございません）
そこでMainCameraにSkyboxコンポーネントを追加し、Skybox内のテクスチャを任意の画像ファイルを指定することで解決しました。

このやり方が正しいとはとても思えませんでしたが、
一応要件は満たせましたのでこちらの方法で一先ず進めさせていただきました。